# SwiftUI Live location update

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, core-location

I have implemented `CLLocationManagerDelegate` in one of my ObservableObjects and I want to be notified whenever the location changes. Everything works but I get "location changed" printed once. My guess is that I should call `manager.startUpdatingLocation()` from outside but I do not know from where exactly.

```
import CoreLocation
import Combine

class LocationManagerService: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    var manager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
    @Published var location: CLLocation?
    @Published var enabled: Bool = false
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        manager.delegate = self
        
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            // manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            manager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        print("location changed") // prints only once
        location = locations.first
        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
    
    func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
        enabled = CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this question is old, but in case somebody wants to use this code use `location = locations.last` instead of `first` to get the latest location (see [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate/1423615-locationmanager))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comment this line that stops the updates

```
location = locations.first 
manager.stopUpdatingLocation() // this
```

Comment: wow that was quick. Thanks!. Is there a way to check if there is a significant location change? Lets say instead of updating it every one cm to update every km?

Comment: you can use `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` instead https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423531-startmonitoringsignificantlocati